# Detect and Edit MP3 Links

Tags: javascript, audio

I need to detect MP3 links within a page using JavaScript, and replace the text with:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3247397568-audio-player.swf?
audioUrl=http://LINK" width="400" height="27" 
allowscriptaccess="never" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" 
wmode="window" flashvars="playerMode=embedded" />
```

with the MP3's URL value?

How would could I do this?

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Whats the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
[].map.call( document.links, function(v){

    if( v.href.indexOf( ".mp3" ) === v.href.length - 4 ) {
        return '<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ' +
            'src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3247397568-audio-player.swf?' +
            'audioUrl='+encodeURIComponent(v.href)+' width="400" height="27" ' +
            'allowscriptaccess="never" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" ' +
            'wmode="window" flashvars="playerMode=embedded" />';
    }

    return "";

}).join("");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e5DSU/2/

The following links on the page:

```
<a href="/asd/asd/asd.mp3"></a>
<a href="/asd/asd/asd.mp3"></a>
<a href="/asd/asd/asd.mp3"></a>
```

give:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3247397568-audio-player.swf?audioUrl=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2Fasd%2Fasd%2Fasd.mp3 width="400" height="27" allowscriptaccess="never" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" wmode="window" flashvars="playerMode=embedded" />
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3247397568-audio-player.swf?audioUrl=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2Fasd%2Fasd%2Fasd.mp3 width="400" height="27" allowscriptaccess="never" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" wmode="window" flashvars="playerMode=embedded" />
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3247397568-audio-player.swf?audioUrl=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2Fasd%2Fasd%2Fasd.mp3 width="400" height="27" allowscriptaccess="never" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" wmode="window" flashvars="playerMode=embedded" />
```

Comment: How can I make it so it leaves the links alone (Or creates a 'Play Audio' link )on mobile browsers

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZVzF6/

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var src=$(this).attr('href');
    var a = src.split('.');
    var ext = a[a.length-1];
    if (ext=='mp3'){

        var html = '<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"                                                                        
                    src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3247397568-audio-player.swf?audioUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(src) + '" 
                    width="400"
                    height="27" allowscriptaccess="never" quality="best" 
                    bgcolor="#ffffff" wmode="window" 
                    flashvars="playerMode=embedded" />';

        $(html).insertAfter($(this));
        $(this).remove();    
    }
});
```

Comment: just FYI `.attr` retrieves attributes which are not the resolved URL's. : `$("a").eq(1).attr("href")` = `"/users/995876/esailija"` vs `$("a").get(1).href` = `"http://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija"`

Comment: How can I make it so it leaves the links alone (Or creates a 'Play Audio' link )on mobile browsers

Comment: Change the html variable to the HTML you want to insert. If you dont want to remove the link, rem out the `$(this).remove();` line