# Detecting and Changing mp3 links javaScript

Tags: javascript, audio

I need help changing

```
<a>'s with a href ending in the .mp3 extension from <a href="audioLink"></a>
```

to

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=audioLink.mp3" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" width="500" height="27" quality="best"></embed>
```

using JavaScript

Comment: Duplicate of [Detect and Edit MP3 Links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537224/detect-and-edit-mp3-links) Please read the FAQ on how the site works if you are new here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By either - jQuery

```
$("a").each(function(){ 
   var link = $(this).attr("href");
   if(~link.indexOf('.mp3')) {
           $("<embed type='application/x-shockwave-flash' flashvars='audioUrl="+link+"' src='http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf' width='500' height='27' quality='best'></embed>").insertAfter(this);
            $(this).remove();
    }

 })
```

or pure Javascript

```
(function( l ){ 
    for( var i=l.length; i--;)
        var link = l[i];
        if(~link.href.indexOf('.mp3')) {
           var p = link.parentNode,
               embed = document.createElement("embed"),
               attr = {  type:'application/x-shockwave-flash',
                         flashvars: 'audioUrl='+link.href,
                         src:'http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf',
                         width:'500',
                         height:'27',
                         quality:'best'}

           for(var j in attr)
               embed[j]=attr[j]
           p.insertBefore(embed,link);
           p.removeChild(link);

        }


})( document.getElementsByTagName( "a" ) )
```

Comment: I *highly* advise using the pure javascript method, attempt running both on a page containing ten thousand links: jquery will crash, pojs will simply work. Good answer.

Comment: it is not at  optimized for speed:
in for loop may caching a length variable   `for(var i=0,_l=links.length;i<_l;i++)`
Instead copying keys from `attr` may pass it all attributes directly:
eg. `embed.width='500'`

Comment: My main issue was that you wern't doing [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aJmuF/) which blocks/crashes.

Comment: @JoshMWilliams I don't understand... each browser has a built in javascript interpreter

Comment: Ok...It works for me on jsfiddle and locally.  Must just be the CMS.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample solution:

```
var links = $(document.body).find('a'), embeded;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i+=1) {
    if ($(links[i]).attr('href').indexOf('.mp3') >= 0) {
        embeded = $('<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl='+ $(links[i]).attr('href') +'" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" width="500" height="27" quality="best"></embed>');
        embeded.insertBefore($(links[i]));
        $(links[i]).remove();
    }
}
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/4JqaA/

Comment: Loading the whole jQuery library adds a lot of bloat for this task, question didn't ask for jQuery solutions either.