# Replace <a> tags with <audio tags> when file type is matched

Tags: javascript, tags

I tried to create a greaseMonkey script that would check a page for mp3s marked up with the `<a>` tag, and replace them with the `<audio>` tag from html5. But I'm having trouble understanding how to do this. Can someone point where I've gone wrong here? Thanks.

```
<html><body>
<!-- tags, might ir might not have ids -->
<a id="myid" href="mp3/basic.phrases.1.mp3">Some mp3 file1.mp3</a><br />
<a href="mp3/basic.phrases.2.mp3">Some mp3 file2.mp3</a><br />

<script language="JavaScript">
var findAtags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for( var i = 0; i < findAtags.length; i++) {
var audioTag = document.createElement("audio");
var ext = findAtags[i].getAttribute("href").split('.').pop();

if(ext == "mp3") {
    document.write(findAtags[i] + '[' + i + '] == ' + ext + '<br>' );
    document.body.replaceChild(audioTag, findAtags[0]);
    // I would need to replace the <a href="..." ></a> with '<audio> <source src="' + findAtags[i] + '" type="audio/mp3" /> </audio>';
};
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting and Changing mp3 links javaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586386/detecting-and-changing-mp3-links-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way without both use any framework and littering global scope.

**Note** - if you'll make iterate by anchors from last to first then you would be able to insert before each of them a element and remove in the same loop.

```
 ( function( a ) {   
     for( var i = a.length; i--; ) {
        var  e  = a[i],
             audio = document.createElement( 'audio' ),
             p = e.parentNode;   

        audio.src = e.href;   
        p.insertBefore( audio, e );
        p.removeChild( e );
     }

    } ) ( document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The line that does the replacing has `findAtags[0]` instead of `findAtags[i]`.

Also, what are you doing with `document.write` there?

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the following, though it seems like it should be possible to make it more concise:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var as = body.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=0,len=as.length; i<len; i++){
    var source = as[i].href;
    var audioElem = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElem.src = source;

    body.insertBefore(audioElem,as[i].nextSibling);    
}

for (var r=as.length - 1; r>=0; r--){
    body.removeChild(as[r]);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fKctV/2/).

Bear in mind that an `audio` element is essentially 'invisible', so while the links are replaced with `audio` elements, you'll have to view the DOM (via Web Inspector, Firebug, Dragonfly...) to 'see' that they're there...